Git Push does not work - error 500 "Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect..."
For a few days now (cannot tell the exact time) i get an error when i try pushing a local repo to Gitlab with 'git push -u origin master'.
For authentification we use a Token.
(With my personal username/password it works, but I need it be called from a C# application using a specific token)
It worked without a problem for months (with the token), but currently i get the error
"remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password"
If i try to push from my C# application using libGit2Sharp, i get the error code 500.
On our Git system i created an access token (Settings - Access Tokens).
Role: "Maintainer"
Scopes: "api, read_api, read_repository, write_repositry".
I even tried "Owner" and checked all scopes.
The error remains.
The only thing which was changed on our Git system was that non-expiring Tokens are not longer allowed.
Does anyone have an idea what could cause this problem?
Thanks a lot!

have you tried regenerating the token?

Yes, several times
